# Declacre CSRF-Token in forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-2.2, csrf-token

I'm using Djangos CSRF-Token the way it's mostly described on the internet:

> MyFormPage.html

```
<form method="POST">  
        {% csrf_token %}  
        {{ form.as_p }}  
</form>
```

But I wonder - is there a way to include it somehow directly in the `forms.py`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good practice or not, but you can do something like:

```
from django.middleware import csrf

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    csrfmiddlewaretoken = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=csrf._get_new_csrf_token())
```

The rendered input field will be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Hsw4uH5jbioQhaWrgAtGgEVp5GbnXIrayuvTqbbABaSxPbGJqksEIxVI4zJW8VVj" id="id_csrfmiddlewaretoken">
```

Comment: Quite interesting it's possible to add it that way. Agree on your question - I'm not sure either if it's supposed to be done like that.

Comment: later I will check if a form can be submitted with this method.